# Writing a book on establishing Cash N Carry business?

Tags: book, business-writing

I am currently writing a book on Cash N Carry and how to establish the business.  Having authored a book on Retail Store Operations, the second venture is this.

For this book I am looking for the role of US in World War II.  Can anyone give me the role played by US towards the beligerent Nations as well its allies?

Cordially yours,

Sriram B Iyer

Comment: You questions don't match (overlooking the fact that your title isn't actually a question anyway). Beyond that, your second question is wildly off topic for this site. Voting to close.

Comment: Questions about the subject matter of your book are off-topic for this site.  If you have questions about the writing itself, that would be a welcome, on-topic question.  Feel free to ask such questions any time.  For questions on history, follow the proposal for a [History.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history).